# Search filter with pure javascript for a grid of images in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am from Azores, Portugal, and i'm working on a project to show the hinking trails of the Azores. I am using a grid of images in html/css to display some of the turism agencies in the azores, but i have a problem with one of the requirements, built a search filter in pure javascript to filter the agencies for island. If someone could help me, I would be grateful, Here is my code!

```
    <section class="oferta">
            <h1 class="titulo">Oferta Turística</h1>

            <div id="btn-container">
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('todas')">Mostrar Todas</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('s-miguel')">São Miguel</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('terceira')">Terceira</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('graciosa')">Graciosa</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('s-jorge')">São Jorge</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('pico')">Pico</button>
                <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('faial')">Faial</button>
            </div>


            <div class="oferta-container">
                <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_getaways.png"></div>
                    <h1>Azores Getaways - São Miguel</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="https://azoresgetaways.com/">WebSite - Azores Getaways</a>
                    <p>Email: - bookings@azoresgetaways.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 308 804 860</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/melo_travel.png"></div>
                    <h1>Melo Travel - São Miguel</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.melotravel.com">WebSite - Melo Travel</a>
                    <p>Email: - info@melotravel.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 296 205 385</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/micaelense.png"></div>
                    <h1>Micaelense - São Miguel</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.micaelense.pt/">WebSite - Micaelense</a>
                    <p>Email: - micaelense@micaelense.net</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 296 206 600</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_dtm.png"></div>
                    <h1>Azores DTM - São Miguel</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.azoresdtm.com/">WebSite - Azores DTM</a>
                    <p>Email: - info@azoresdtm.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 300 501 800</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro terceira">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/angra_travel.png"></div>
                    <h1>Angratravel - Terceira</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://angratravel.com/pt">WebSite - Angratravel</a>
                    <p>Email: - reservasangratravel@outlook.pt</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 295 206 900/10</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro terceira">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_travel.png"></div>
                    <h1>Azores Travel - Terceira</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.azorestravel.pt/">WebSite - Azores Travel</a>
                    <p>Email: - azorestravel.turismo@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 963 800 339</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro terceira">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/turangra.png"></div>
                    <h1>Turangra - Terceira</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="https://turangra.com/">WebSite - Turangra</a>
                    <p>Email: - incoming@turangra.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 295 204 040</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro graciosa">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/via_graciosa.png"></div>
                    <h1>Via Graciosa - Graciosa</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.viagraciosa.com/">WebSite - Via Graciosa</a>
                    <p>Email: - geral@viagraciosa.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 295 732 981/2</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/aquarius.png"></div>
                    <h1>Aquarius - São Jorge</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.viagensaquarius.com">WebSite - Aquarius</a>
                    <p>Email: - aquariustravel@mail.telepac.pt</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 295 432 006/7</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/via_s_jorge.png"></div>
                    <h1>Via São Jorge - São Jorge</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.viasaojorge.com">WebSite - Via São Jorge</a>
                    <p>Email: - geral@viasaojorge.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 295 416 042/3/4</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azooree.png"></div>
                    <h1>Azooree - São Jorge</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.azooree.com">WebSite - Azooree</a>
                    <p>Email: - hello@azooree.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 966 201 309</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro pico">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/fonte_travel.png"></div>
                    <h1>Fonte Travel - Pico</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.fontetravel.com">WebSite - Fonte Travel</a>
                    <p>Email: - info@fontetravel.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 292 679 505</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro pico">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/natura_lusitana.png"></div>
                    <h1>Natura Lusitana - Pico</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://natura-lusitana.com">WebSite - Natura Lusitana</a>
                    <p>Email: - info@natura-lusitana.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 910 253 343</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro faial">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/ourisland.png"></div>
                    <h1>Ourisland - Faial</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.ourisland-azores.com/">WebSite - Ourisland</a>
                    <p>Email: - info@ourisland-azores.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 967 172 754</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item filtro faial">
                    <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/aerohorta.png"></div>
                    <h1>Aero Horta - Faial</h1>
                    <h2>Contactos:</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.aerohorta.com">WebSite - Aero Horta</a>
                    <p>Email: - incoming@aerohorta.com</p>
                    <p>Telefone: +351 292 208 130</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
<script>
    function selecaoFiltro(elemento){
        if(elemento != "todas"){ 

            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("filtro");

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){

            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        var y = document.getElementById(elemento).style.display = "block";
        for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) j
            y[j].style.display = 'block';
        }

    else{ 
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("filtro");

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){

            x[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First we select all the elements with the class `filtro`, then we filter from the selected class.

```js
 function selecaoFiltro(filter) {
     var all = document.querySelectorAll('.filtro');

     if (filter == 'todas') {
         all.forEach(function(e) {
             e.style.display = 'block';
         });
     } else {
         all.forEach(function(e) {
             if (e.classList.contains(filter)) {
                 e.style.display = 'block';
             } else {
                 e.style.display = 'none';
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

```html
<section class="oferta">
    <h1 class="titulo">Oferta Turística</h1>

    <div id="btn-container">
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('todas')">Mostrar Todas</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('s-miguel')">São Miguel</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('terceira')">Terceira</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('graciosa')">Graciosa</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('s-jorge')">São Jorge</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('pico')">Pico</button>
        <button class="btn-oferta active" onclick="selecaoFiltro('faial')">Faial</button>
    </div>


    <div class="oferta-container">
        <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_getaways.png"></div>
            <h1>Azores Getaways - São Miguel</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="https://azoresgetaways.com/">WebSite - Azores Getaways</a>
            <p>Email: - bookings@azoresgetaways.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 308 804 860</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/melo_travel.png"></div>
            <h1>Melo Travel - São Miguel</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.melotravel.com">WebSite - Melo Travel</a>
            <p>Email: - info@melotravel.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 296 205 385</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/micaelense.png"></div>
            <h1>Micaelense - São Miguel</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.micaelense.pt/">WebSite - Micaelense</a>
            <p>Email: - micaelense@micaelense.net</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 296 206 600</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-miguel">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_dtm.png"></div>
            <h1>Azores DTM - São Miguel</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.azoresdtm.com/">WebSite - Azores DTM</a>
            <p>Email: - info@azoresdtm.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 300 501 800</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro terceira">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/angra_travel.png"></div>
            <h1>Angratravel - Terceira</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://angratravel.com/pt">WebSite - Angratravel</a>
            <p>Email: - reservasangratravel@outlook.pt</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 295 206 900/10</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro terceira">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azores_travel.png"></div>
            <h1>Azores Travel - Terceira</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.azorestravel.pt/">WebSite - Azores Travel</a>
            <p>Email: - azorestravel.turismo@gmail.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 963 800 339</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro terceira">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/turangra.png"></div>
            <h1>Turangra - Terceira</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="https://turangra.com/">WebSite - Turangra</a>
            <p>Email: - incoming@turangra.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 295 204 040</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro graciosa">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/via_graciosa.png"></div>
            <h1>Via Graciosa - Graciosa</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.viagraciosa.com/">WebSite - Via Graciosa</a>
            <p>Email: - geral@viagraciosa.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 295 732 981/2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/aquarius.png"></div>
            <h1>Aquarius - São Jorge</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.viagensaquarius.com">WebSite - Aquarius</a>
            <p>Email: - aquariustravel@mail.telepac.pt</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 295 432 006/7</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/via_s_jorge.png"></div>
            <h1>Via São Jorge - São Jorge</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.viasaojorge.com">WebSite - Via São Jorge</a>
            <p>Email: - geral@viasaojorge.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 295 416 042/3/4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro s-jorge">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/azooree.png"></div>
            <h1>Azooree - São Jorge</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.azooree.com">WebSite - Azooree</a>
            <p>Email: - hello@azooree.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 966 201 309</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro pico">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/fonte_travel.png"></div>
            <h1>Fonte Travel - Pico</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.fontetravel.com">WebSite - Fonte Travel</a>
            <p>Email: - info@fontetravel.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 292 679 505</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro pico">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/natura_lusitana.png"></div>
            <h1>Natura Lusitana - Pico</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://natura-lusitana.com">WebSite - Natura Lusitana</a>
            <p>Email: - info@natura-lusitana.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 910 253 343</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro faial">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/ourisland.png"></div>
            <h1>Ourisland - Faial</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.ourisland-azores.com/">WebSite - Ourisland</a>
            <p>Email: - info@ourisland-azores.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 967 172 754</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item filtro faial">
            <div class="oferta-item" style="background-image: url(imgs/oferta/aerohorta.png"></div>
            <h1>Aero Horta - Faial</h1>
            <h2>Contactos:</h2>
            <a href="http://www.aerohorta.com">WebSite - Aero Horta</a>
            <p>Email: - incoming@aerohorta.com</p>
            <p>Telefone: +351 292 208 130</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```